# Redelivery is ignored in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.4.0

Tags: configuration, activemq-artemis

I configured Artemis to redeliver faild messages like this (broker.xml):

```
<address-setting match="#">
    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>`enter code here`
    <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
    <redelivery-delay>30000</redelivery-delay>
    <max-redelivery-delay>30000</max-redelivery-delay>
</address-setting>

[...]

<address-setting match="email">
    <redelivery-delay-multiplier>3</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
    <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
    <max-redelivery-delay>86400000</max-redelivery-delay>
</address-setting>

[...]

<addresses>
    <address name="email">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="email" />
        </anycast>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

I use Springboot as sender and receiver. After sending a message to the queue it appears in artemis' queue and the receiver is called. The processing fails. But instead of putting the message back to the queue and try to redeliver it, this happens:

`09:57:37,672 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222149: Message Reference[53]:RELIABLE:CoreMessage[messageID=53,durable=true,userID=null,priority=4, timestamp=Mon Jan 29 09:57:37 UTC 2018,expiration=0, durable=
 true, address=email,properties=TypedProperties[__HDR_dlqDeliveryFailureCause=java.lang.Throwable: Delivery[1] exceeds redelivery policy limit:RedeliveryPolicy {destination = null, collisionAvoidanceFactor = 0.15, maximumRedeli
 veries = 0, maximumRedeliveryDelay = -1, initialRedeliveryDelay = 1000, useCollisionAvoidance = false, useExponentialBackOff = false, backOffMultiplier = 5.0, redeliveryDelay = 1000, preDispatchCheck = true}, cause:null,__HDR_
 BROKER_IN_TIME=1517219857591,interaction_id=b0b5cb2c618f4605a11ad599dfd7f54b,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,__HDR_ARRIVAL=0,__HDR_GROUP_SEQUENCE=0,__HDR_COMMAND_ID=36,__HDR_MARSHALL_PROP=[0000 0001 000E 696E 7465 7261 6374 696F 6E5F 6964
  0900 2062 3062 3563 6232 6336 3138 6634 3630 3561 3131 6164 3539 3964 6664 3766 3534 62),__HDR_PRODUCER_ID=[0000 003D 7B01 0029 4944 3A64 652D 6164 6E2D 6266 786A 6E63 322D 3532 3232  ... 37 3231 3934 3238 3032 362D 313A 3100
  0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 09),_AMQ_DUPL_ID=ID:de-adn-bfxjnc2-52228-1517219428026-1:1:9:1:3,__HDR_MESSAGE_ID=[0000 0050 6E00 017B 0100 2949 443A 6465 2D61 646E 2D62 6678 6A6E 6332 2D35  ...  0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0
 000 0009 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000 0000 0000 0000),__HDR_DROPPABLE=false]]@693556289 has reached maximum delivery attempts, sending it to Dead Letter Address DLQ from email`

It looks to me as if my configuration is completely ignored.
Can anybody tell me, what is wron in my configuration?

Comment: What kind of client are you using?

Comment: I'm using SpringBoot as sender (JmsTemplate) and receiver (JmsListener).

Comment: I meant what client library are you using.  There are many JMS implementations that will work with ActiveMQ Artemis (e.g. JMS "core" client, JMS OpenWire client, QPID JMS).  What client library are you using?

Comment: Ah ok. I think, It's JMS OpenWire, that I use.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the OpenWire support in Artemis, but historically I can say that redelivery semantics have always been controlled by the OpenWire client itself and are configured on the connection factory (see http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html).  Try this approach or, alternately, you might change JMS libraries (e.g. to the "core" JMS implementation shipped with the broker).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I have tried the sam with ActiveMQ an it worked fine.
There is only a problem with Artemis.

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically what you tried with ActiveMQ 5.x.  The broker configuration and JNDI implementations are different.  I assume you created what you feel is an equivalent configuration.  Can you elaborate on that?  In any cast, if you think this is a bug in Artemis' OpenWire compatibility please create a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS and attach a reproducible test-case.